# How to apply dtplyr with SQL Server database

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr, dbplyr, dtplyr

I am trying to apply dtplyr to a SQL Server database.

I succeeded in applying dplyr as shown below, but I don't know how to apply dtplyr

How can I do this?

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(dtplyr)
library(dbplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver    = "SQL Server", 
                      Server    = "address",
                      Database  = "dbname",
                      UID       = "ID",
                      PWD       = "password")

dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("dbo", "table1"))
```

Comment: The example you provide seems related to [dbplyr](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/). What do you need `dtplyr` for?

Comment: `dtplyr` is for data processing using `data.table`, it doesn't handle the SQL Server connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments by @Waldi capture the essence of the matter. You can **not** use dtplyr with SQL Server as it only translates commands to `data.table` objects.

The official [dtplyr documentation](https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/) states:

> The goal of dtplyr is to allow you to write dplyr code that is automatically translated to the equivalent ... data.table code

The official [dbplyr documentatio](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/)n states:

> It allows you to use remote database tables as if they are in-memory data frames by automatically converting dplyr code into SQL

Both dbplyr and dtplyr translate dplyr commands. Which one you use depends on whether you are working with `data.table` type objects (in R memory) or remote SQL databases (whichever flavor of SQL you prefer).